# firewall-cmd filtrar por string

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, centos7

Buenas estoy intentando filtrar por String una cadena, igual como se hace en iptables; pero no me funciona. estoy mandando la secuencia así.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -s xx.xx.xx.xx -p tcp --dport 443 -m string --string "youtube" --algo bm -j DROP
```

Alguien ha intentado filtrar por String en firewalld en Centos 7? en iptables funciona pero en firewalld? quiero filtrar youtube y el único método que encontré es el String.

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero creo que el problema es que el trafico con destino al puerto 443 no "viaja" en texto plano, sino cifrado con SSL, por eso tu filtro no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas hacer no es posible, el tráfico que viaja a través del puerto 443 son conexiones seguras, por lo tanto no es posible realizar filtros sobre el contenido.

Se podría establecer una relación de certificados entre tu firewall y el sitio con el que quieres establecer el filtro, de esta forma el usuario no realizaría la petición sino el firewall, a esto se le llama 'inspection SSL'